# Possible to stagger lead tasks?

Tags: tasks, queue

I have 100 leads. I want my sales person to get a task to contact the first 25 the first day, the next 25 the next day etc.

So they would get 25 tasks a day, instead of 100 all at once.

I know you can do timed workflows, but I need a queue type system. I have looked at Queues but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Comment: 1) and what happens when more Leads come in tomorrow?

Comment: Without code, it's going to be awfully hard to get things going just the way you want. You may even have to trust your users.

Comment: @sfdcfox Definitely looking like I will have to code something up. And it is more than just trusting my users. I don't want to bury them. We have 1000 leads for this process, I didn't want to dump 500 tasks on them in 1 day. :)